# How to set dimensions of image items in GridView to fill spaces

Tags: android, xml, gridview, imageview, picasso

I want to make the images in the grid view be with a bigger size according to the screen size, even when I use wrap content to the image view & make the number of columns fixed it also leave spaces, I download images by Picasso
my code:

**gridview**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**image view**

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/posterImage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```

[my grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhBXG.png)

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxuRX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your `layout_height` and `layout_width` parameter manually instead of 
`wrap_content`

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/posterImage"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:layout_width="370dp">
</ImageView>
```

It is best practice to put dp margins into dimen.xml file.

also in gridView, you should change `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`;